# ReSharper - browser test page session not lasting

Tags: unit-testing, session, resharper, qunit

All my QUnit tests run okay with ReSharper, but QUnit's generated page will be shown only once. The session will be gone at page reload or even after trying to filter the tests in the filter options (Chrome gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`). *"Save and restore Unit Test Sessions"* is marked.

Does this have something to do with the tests always running in a different port? I wanted the page to stay where it is for later use, but I can't figure out how to do it. How do I make the session last without the connection being refused after a page reload?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Juan Unfortunately not. I gave up from it and started using [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html), which IMHO is way superior than ReSharper's automated tests functionality.

Comment: Thank you @Pedro. If anyone else reads this, I did end up finding a document saying that ReSharper closes the web server as soon as the request is done on purpose in later versions of the product. I personally ended up downloading an extension called Chutzpah. Now I just right click on the test and select an option to run it. From there on, the file stays open (it's file based) and I can debug with the browser's Developer tools.